# OS Authentication might be disabled for this database

Tags: oracle-19c

LINUX X64 193000 software installed on "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.9 (Maipo)"

DBCA:

GUI or silent install always fails with:

```
[FATAL] [DBT-05509] Failed to connect to the specified database (cdb1).
CAUSE: OS Authentication might be disabled for this database (cdb1).
ACTION: Specify a valid sysdba user name and password to connect to the database.
```

I have googled - no help.

I have an SR open and sent them an RDA report.  But all I do is upload env variables or send screen shots to no avail.

I've never experienced this before and I (and I guess MOS) are out of ideas.

Here is my silent script:

[image: silent install]

EDIT: What I see with ssqlplus

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

 SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Oct 27 17:19:33 2021
 Version 19.3.0.0.0
 ERROR:
 ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Enter user-name:

EDIT2:

ORACLE_UNQNAME=cdb1
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
ORACLE_SID=cdb1
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
ORA_INVENTORY=/u01/app/oraInventory
ORAENV_ASK=NO
CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/19/dbhome_1
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/u01/app/oracle/product/19/dbhome_1/bin

EDIT3:

Doesn't get very far

[image]

Comment: @ ik_zelf  I updated the question with the answer, thanks.

Comment: If you put OH first, vi and the like does not work

Comment: removed non-oracle,all exported, re-ran, same result

Comment: yes, you are correct!  echo $PATH ;   /u01/app/oracle/product/19/dbhome_1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin  Re-run. Same error

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/19/dbhome_1/lib

Comment: Did you check the requirements https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/supported-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7-distributions-for-x86-64.html#GUID-2E11B561-6587-4789-A583-2E33D705E498 and ran root.sh after the installation?

Comment: Did you check DBCA Fails To Create Oracle 19c Database On AIX [DBT-05509] (Doc ID 2663388.1 could be valid for Linux too.

Comment: I did run root scripts.  I ran them again and it failed again

Comment: If the bug report does not help, wait for your SR. Did you install oracle database software before?

Comment: Before as in "before I ran DBCA" or before as in "have you ever installed Oracle or Oracle 19c before" ?  Either way YES to both.

Comment: i have the same error if u resolved it please share your solution

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what kind of oracle setup you have.
In one of my cases where I have installed clusterware for a single instance, the clusterware was installed as grid user while the binaries for the database were installed under user oracle.
I got this exact problem. The issue was that I have inadvertently set the ownership of the oracle home directories to `grid:oinstall` instead of `oracle:oinstall` (some install are using `oracle:dba`). Changing all the dirs to the correct owner fixed the error. All the rest of the variables the SRs were pointing were set OK.